# Deploying django application to SaaS PaaS or IaaS

Tags: django, deployment

My project is almost ready for deployment. But there is two important things to configure because deployment is different than local development. My project is a cloud management software having to do with medical and doctors. It deals with a lot of pictures with a lot of mb's. So I am in the look out for where to deploy and how to serve my static files. I also want to know how to deal with new instance of my web app. What I mean is:

1. My application gives users the ability to upload images and manipulate them. The images will be large in size, and quality cannot be easily compromised. I am talking about 100gb per practice.
2. I want to be able automatically through my website which will work as a dashboard, to easily create new instances of my application for every new client that pays. The instances must have different databases. The credentials of the database must be set during creation (e.g the username could be the id of a new client). The instances must be something like this: wwww.mydomain.com/practice1, www.mydomain.com/practice2.
3. Choose from all those different deployment choices. I mean IaaS, PaaS, SaaS. Since I am fairly new to this which one meets my needs judging by what I have described so far?
4. I should also be able to easily set up static and media files. My boss asked me this too: If it is possible to keep original images in a cloud storage and store only lower quality images on the server, in order to comfort webserver load but not loose initial image with full quality. Can it be done? Would you suggest it?

How would you go to deploy a web app like the one I am describing?

Comment: I suggest you to create one thread for each one of your questions, because each one may create a big debate.

Comment: Oh alright...just didn't want to flood with questions about the same issue. Will do... thanks

Comment: would be good to get a link to the questions here if you created them - thanks!